# How to see background process and log in android studio when using Blue Stack as emulator?

Tags: android, bluestacks

Blue Stack log and process.

I really love using Blue Stack as emulator, but only when the app does not has errors. Clearly I can not find the way to see LOG in android studio and in tab "`Run`" I also do not see any processes running, so I have to switch between real phone and Blue Stack, this is really annoying, since I do not have an android phone and my company does not have much phone for employees. So how I can make BLUE STACK emulator work like a real phone or like "`Genymotion`" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, they are the same thing but Bluestack doesn't have the config file that will send the log to Android Studio. Where you can relive totally on Genymotion as it is a better option.

Comment: Yeah, but my laptop run Genymotion not really well, even thought i pass the requirement and i set the RAM is 4GB. It does not smooth like Blue Stack.

Comment: Update to 12/16GB and then use Android Emulator. They are great we use them for development rather than Genymotion